# instantiate a class from a variable in PHP?

Tags: php, class, variables, eval

I know this question sounds rather vague so I will make it more clear with an example:

```
$var = 'bar';
$bar = new {$var}Class('var for __construct()'); //$bar = new barClass('var for __construct()');
```

This is what I want to do. How would you do it? I could off course use eval() like this:

```
$var = 'bar';
eval('$bar = new '.$var.'Class(\'var for __construct()\');');
```

But I'd rather stay away from eval(). Is there any way to do this without eval()?

Answer (score 251, accepted):

Put the classname into a variable first:

```
$classname=$var.'Class';

$bar=new $classname("xyz");
```

This is often the sort of thing you'll see wrapped up in a Factory pattern.

See [Namespaces and dynamic language features](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.dynamic.php) for further details.

Comment: This is how I do it. Note that from within classes you can use parent and self.

Comment: On a similar note, you can also do $var = 'Name'; $obj->{'get'.$var}();

Comment: Good point, though that only works for method calls and not constructors

Comment: If you work with namespace, put the current namespace into the string: `$var = __NAMESPACE__ . '\\' . $var . 'Class';`

Comment: @bastey - but why? I just spent too much time on figuring out, why this wouldn't work without the namespace preceding the class name...

Answer (score 98):

## If You Use Namespaces

In my own findings, I think it's good to mention that you (as far as I can tell) must declare the full namespace path of a class.

MyClass.php

```
namespace com\company\lib;
class MyClass {
}
```

index.php

```
namespace com\company\lib;

//Works fine
$i = new MyClass();

$cname = 'MyClass';

//Errors
//$i = new $cname;

//Works fine
$cname = "com\\company\\lib\\".$cname;
$i = new $cname;
```

Comment: The only working solution when need to create with namespace, are yours. Thanks for share!

Comment: But this is just weird, Why would it not use the declared namespace ?

Comment: @YisraelDov Yes it is definitely counter intuitive.  But for whatever reason it does behave weirdly in this context. Thanks php

Comment: @YisraelDov I guess it is because in that case instantiating a class from another namespace would be huge headache. Also consider that variables can be passed around. When the classname is written as text into a php file, whoever writes it knows exactly what namespace it is written in. But when a variable is passed between functions, it'd be a nightmare to follow up on it. Also if you use get_class() it'll give back the FQ classname, so that can be stored in a variable straight away and used anywhere. If it was depending on the namespace of the file, it wouldn't work very well.

Comment: @BenceSzalai imo counter intuitive functionality isn't worth forced explicitness.  I think if I had a bug because of namespaces, it'd be somewhat evident to me and/or if i want to force the namespace I easily can.  Those issues seem easier to debug or fix to me than why it doesn't work as one would intuit it should (aka if new MyClass() works then new $"MyClass"() should also work).

Answer (score 64):

### How to pass dynamic constructor parameters too

If you want to pass dynamic constructor parameters to the class, you can use this code:

```
$reflectionClass = new ReflectionClass($className);

$module = $reflectionClass->newInstanceArgs($arrayOfConstructorParameters);
```

[More information on dynamic classes and parameters](http://rabaix.net/en/articles/2009/02/06/how-to-instantiate-a-php-class-with-dynamic-parameters)

#### PHP >= 5.6

As of PHP 5.6 you can simplify this even more by using [Argument Unpacking](http://php.net/manual/en/migration56.new-features.php#migration56.new-features.splat):

```
// The "..." is part of the language and indicates an argument array to unpack.
$module = new $className(...$arrayOfConstructorParameters);
```

Thanks to DisgruntledGoat for pointing that out.

Comment: From PHP 5.6 you should be able to use argument unpacking: `new $className(...$params)`

Answer (score 32):

```
class Test {
    public function yo() {
        return 'yoes';
    }
}

$var = 'Test';

$obj = new $var();
echo $obj->yo(); //yoes
```

Comment: No, not a good example. Only works if everything is in the same php file.

Comment: 2ndGAB should remove this comment. Autoloading has nothing to do with this question.

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend the `call_user_func()` or `call_user_func_array`php methods.
You can check them out here ([call_user_func_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php) , [call_user_func](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func.php)).

example

```
class Foo {
static public function test() {
    print "Hello world!\n";
}
}

 call_user_func('Foo::test');//FOO is the class, test is the method both separated by ::
 //or
 call_user_func(array('Foo', 'test'));//alternatively you can pass the class and method as an array
```

If you have arguments you are passing to the method , then use the `call_user_func_array()` function.

example.

```
class foo {
function bar($arg, $arg2) {
    echo __METHOD__, " got $arg and $arg2\n";
}
}

// Call the $foo->bar() method with 2 arguments
call_user_func_array(array("foo", "bar"), array("three", "four"));
//or
//FOO is the class, bar is the method both separated by ::
call_user_func_array("foo::bar"), array("three", "four"));
```

Comment: This answer doesn't apply to the question. OP is asking how to INSTANTIATE a class (triggering the class __construct method dynamically) from a variable string and getting the CLASS OBJECT back in a new variable -- your advice will return the VALUE of the class->method([ ]) you're calling, not the class object so doesn't apply for this case. See the return value http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php