# Declaring variable as PHP class

Tags: php, class

I have a variable called $theclass and it's a string "Home_class". How can I define a class out of that string? The reason I need to do this is that the variable will change and I want to be able to declare the class that the variable is equal to.

Comment: possible duplicate of [instantiate a class from a variable in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/534159/instantiate-a-class-from-a-variable-in-php)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `new` keyword.

```
$theclass = 'My_class';
$x = new $theclass(); // $x is now an instance of My_class
```

Comment: that works perfecly, I have to wait 11 minutes to mark answer as correct though. Thanks.