# PHP - creating class object with the desired type, according to var

Tags: php, class

Is there anyway to create a class object *type* based on var value ?

Example for what I would like to do:

Say I have some dozens of classes: ClassA, ClassB and ClassC,... that are all extends of ClassBasic class. So they have the same interface function `doOperation()`,  but different internal implementation.

```
// the variable contains the name of the desired class type.
$TypeToCreate = "ClassC";

// create the desired type of class
$ClassObj = new $TypeToCreate;   

// do some operation of the created class.
$ClassObj->doOperation();
```

Comment: This is what the [Factory Pattern](http://www.phptherightway.com/pages/Design-Patterns.html) solves

Comment: $ClassObj = new $TypeToCreate should work , what is the issue?

Comment: Use Factory Pattern, or see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/534159/instantiate-a-class-from-a-variable-in-php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, but mpm was right, 
it works. And its ok.

I also will take a look for the Factor Pattern in order to see what is it about.

Thanks!