# Is it possible to retrieve a classname using its name saved in a string in PHP?

Tags: php, php-5.5, php-5.6

I have a classname saved in a string in PHP. 
Is it possible to resolve the class name using a string?

If assuming that I have a class called 'Myclass', I need something like:

```
'Myclass'::class
```

Comment: All data from your input will looks exactly like this?

Comment: I don't get, which input?

Comment: @naneri do you want to use it like this `$dynamic_name_of_the_class::class`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [instantiate a class from a variable in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/534159/instantiate-a-class-from-a-variable-in-php)

Comment: @HoschNok no, I need to get a full class name out of a string without creating an object that is a class instance.

Comment: Please elaborate. In what way will/may the "full classname" differ from 'Myclass' ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely clear what use you'd have for `::class` against a string. The simple fact is that, if this worked, it would just output the same string as you already have. ie in your example, `'MyClass'::class` would output the string `MyClass`.

Maybe you're trying to have a string that just contains the classname and you're trying to resolve the namespace? This won't work. But you can get the current namespace using the `__NAMESPACE__` reserved word:

```
namespace foo\bar;
echo __NAMESPACE__;  //will output 'foo\bar'
```

You can use this in conjunction with a classname string to build a fully-qualified classname for the current namespace.

If you want to get a classname from a different namespace, then you will have to know the namespace beforehand; without the namespace, PHP won't be able to locate the class at all.