# Class not found, when trying to pass class name as string, namespace issue

Tags: php, class, oop, namespaces

Here is a method, in which a string is passed, using that string an instance is created. Example method:

```
public function action($actionType)
{
    //var_dump(new $actionType);

    if (!class_exists($actionType)) {
        //throw new Exception

    }

    if (!(new $actionType) instanceof ActionInterface) {
        ////throw new Exception
    }
    $actionType = new $actionType;
    echo $actionType->doAction();
}
```

But I am getting an error of class not found, however when I manually  write the class name or manually append the namespace this way  `$actionType = __namespace__ . "\\$actionType";`, then error goes. Why is that happening?

Comment: Try to replace new $actionType; with new $actionType();

Comment: @stweb isn't creating an instance of a class without parentheses a short hand for not passing any parameters to the constructor?

Comment: Also, I would put the `$actionType = new $actionType;` between the if statements to avoid creating two instances. In the last if-statement you would do: `if (!$actionType instanceof ActionInterface) { }`

Comment: @harry123 are you using some kind of autoloading?

Comment: Replace if (!$actionType instanceof ActionInterface) with if (!($actionType instanceof ActionInterface)). About parentheses, I agree wuth @Rasmus Rosengren, you can skip it.

Comment: I suspect that PHP does not add default namespaces when processing variables in commands like 'new'.  maybe interesting? [instantiate a class from a variable in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/534159/instantiate-a-class-from-a-variable-in-php). Useful: manual: [Namespaces and dynamic language features](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.dynamic.php) .

Comment: @harry123 could you please show us your project structure and what the files/class you are trying to load look like

Comment: @RasmusRosengren yes, I am using Composer autoload class

Comment: Could you give us more information?

Comment: Is the namespace static or dynamic?

Comment: namespace of this class is something like this `namespace\subNamespace`, and folder structure is like this `app\namespace\subNamespace`, and from where I am loading the classes is index.php which is outside of the `app` directory.

Comment: Add  more details to your question

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public function action($actionType) {
     //var_dump(new $actionType);
     if (!class_exists($actionType)) {
       //throw new Exception
     }
     $actionType = new $actionType;
     if (!($actionType instanceof ActionInterface)) {
        ////throw new Exception
     }

     echo $actionType->doAction();
}
```

Comment: this doesn't make any difference.