# use namespace with variable in name

Tags: php, oop, namespaces

I am working on something, just practicing and I don't have that much experience. I am using namespaces and I have one functions in class namespaced under 'App\Core' which should include another file with different class and namespaced under 'App\Diff' and return that new class.
i.e.

```
namespace App\Core;

class Test {
    public function testFunc($file) {
        require_once "../folder/" . $file . ".php";
        return new $file();
    }
}
```

now class inside $file

```
namespace App\Diff;

class Test2 {
}
```

I tried something like return

```
new App\Diff . "\{$file()}";
```

but I got an error "Class App\Code\App\Diff not found ..."

Comment: What happen if you put another backslash at the front like `new \App\Diff` ?

Comment: Class App\Diff not found.

Comment: How do you instantiate the `Test` class and call the `testFunc()` ?

Comment: I call it from another class. `use App\Core\Test;` and call it from within a function `public function function callTest() { $a = $this->b->testFunc('ClassName'); }` and b is an instance of Test class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As frz3993 mentions that first you have go in global space than you can access `\App\Diff` and your class . see the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.rules.php)
Second problem i don't have correct solution but you can see last answer of **csga5000** [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/534159/instantiate-a-class-from-a-variable-in-php) & [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.dynamic.php)

```
namespace App\Core;

class Test {
    public function testFunc($file) {
        require_once "../folder/" . $file . ".php";
         $f = "\\App\\Diff\\".$file ;
         return new $f;
    }
}
```

Comment: That actually worked. Thanks, I'll read it and continue with my project.