# In CodeIgniter 3, Can I create a new Class instance using a variable?

Tags: php, codeigniter, factory-pattern

This code works...

```
$season_view_builder =  new Hockey_season_view_builder($season_id);
```

However, if I use the following code I get the white screen of death.

```
$builder = 'Hockey_season_view_builder';
$season_view_builder =  new $builder($season_id);
```

Can CodeIgniter create new class instances from a variable name?  Is there some kind of weird codeigniter syntax to this?

I really need to generate and return new classes dynamically to make my factory pattern work.

Thanks for any help!  I'll keep trying different approaches and post if I find anything.

Comment: What does this have to do with codeigniter? Ci3 classes are loaded via the `load` method not by requiring and issuing a `new`

Answer (score 0):

I was looking at [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/534159/instantiate-a-class-from-a-variable-in-php) and saw the correct answer which had to do with using namespaces.  I've kind of hacked my CodeIgniter to use namespaces so I needed to do

```
$builder = 'Hockey_season_view_builder';
$var = __NAMESPACE__ . '\\' . $builder;
$season_view_builder =  new $var($season_id);
```

Thank you and sorry about the foolish question.

Comment: If you really need namespaces use a more modern framework like laravel or symphony. Ci4 is in development and will support namespaces, and all the modern stuff but isn't ready yet. Ci3 seems an odd choice.