# How can I create object from string type variable in php?

Tags: php, oop

I want to create object from string type variable but I'm failed.
I am trying this -

**My code:**

```
$variableName="I am a novice OOP programmer";
$variableInstance= new $variableName();

echo $variableInstance;
```

**Output notice is**
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'I am a novice OOP programmer' not found

**If you kindly get me another answer what is fatal error? And why it may be shown?**

Comment: You are getting the fatal error because the class doesn't actually exist.  In order to accomplish what you are after you need to define a class first.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [instantiate a class from a variable in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/534159/instantiate-a-class-from-a-variable-in-php)

Comment: @Jewel, have you read the duplicate link?

Comment: Do you understand you can't create an object if the class has not been defined? `$variableName` in your example, needs to be **the name of an existing class**.