# Why PHP asks to pass arguments to the anonymous class?

Tags: php, oop

I am trying to create an anonymous class which extends an abstract class.

```
$trainerEngineClass = new class extends \App\MemoryBoost\TrainerEngine {
    public function __construct($user, $trainer) {
        parent::__construct($user, $trainer);
    }

    // Abstract method implementation here
};
```

PHP shows an error:

> Too few arguments to function class@anonymous::__construct(), 0 passed in TrainerController.php on line 74 and exactly 2 expected

I excepted that `__construct` will not be called, but it seems that it called. I want to create a **class**, not an **object** of this class

What should I do to create a class object?

Comment: `new class` creates an object.

Comment: Creating an anonymous class without also instantiating it would be entirely useless. How would you identify your nameless class in order to instantiate it? If you want a class, create one in the normal way. If you want the object, pass the prameters you have defined.

Comment: I've never heard the term *create* applied to class definition. Classes are defined, objects of classes are created. What is "create class*? What should it do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At the very end, you are instantiating a class, so, the constructor is been fired. Anonymous classes, as it's mentioned in the [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.oop5.anonymous.php), are useful for creating single and uniques objects, not for creating a template.

The syntax for passing params through is:

```
$trainerEngineClass = new class($user, $trainer) extends \App\MemoryBoost\TrainerEngine {
        public function __construct($user, $trainer) {
            parent::__construct($user, $trainer);
        }

        // Overriden abstract methods
    };
```

Comment: Do I understand correctly that there's no way to create a class variable?

Comment: Checkout this resource: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/534159/instantiate-a-class-from-a-variable-in-php . Anyways, I'd use factory design pattern  instead

Comment: The interesting thing is that PHP seems to not only *define* an anonymous class, but *instantiates* it as well. This doesn't work: `$c=new class(0){function __construct(DateTime$p){}}`. But this does: `$c=new class(new DateTime){function __construct(DateTime$p){}}`